# load image with glide and change image view width base on image width

Tags: java, android, image, android-glide

I am loading image into recycle view with Glide library, with large image every thing is fine but when image size is small I want decrease image view width to avoid low quality view ,I try these lines of code but its not work all time and change all image size when reload image:

```
 Glide.with(context).load(url).listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {


                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {

                        ((imageHolder) holder).pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        final GifDrawable gifDrawable;
                        if (resource instanceof Animatable) {
                            gifDrawable = (GifDrawable) resource;
                            gifDrawable.start();
                        } else {
                            gifDrawable = null;
                        }
                        int imageViewWidth = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                        if (getScreenWidth() > (2.5 * resource.getIntrinsicWidth())) {
                            imageViewWidth = getScreenWidth() / 2;

                        } else {
                        }
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(imageViewWidth, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        ((imageHolder) holder).imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
                        return false;
                    }
                }).apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.s).centerInside()).into(((imageHolder) holder).imageView);
```

**and this my xml:**

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/p_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"

    />
```

and I have to say I can not get Image size without download it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try 
.centerCrop()?

change centerInside with centerCrop